# Direct and Indirect relation concept

Tags: ratio

Que - 100 million bacteria can completely decompose a garbage dump in 15 days and 60 million bacteria can do so in 30 days. If same quantity of garbage is added to the initial quantity of the dump everyday, how many bacteria will be required to completely decompose the dump in 10 days

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Generally in rate questions like these in mathematics, there is a tacit assumption that the rate is constant. But that assumption is contradicted by the data provided: Cutting the time in half is accomplished by increasing the number of bacteria by only $2/3$. Under the tacit assumption, it should have required doubling the amount of bacteria. Obviously some other model is being used here. But there is no information to tell us what this other model should be. So without more information, the problem is not solvable.